# Accessing swift class extension methods from within original class

Tags: swift, swift2, protocols, swift-extensions, swift-protocols

The below code does not compile for me:

```
import Foundation  
@objc public protocol MyProtocol {  
    func protocolMethod(parameter: (String)) -> String  
    func anotherProtocolMethod() -> Int  
}  
class MyClass: NSObject {  
    var myValue = self.anotherProtocolMethod()  
}  
extension MyClass: MyProtocol {  
    func protocolMethod(parameter: (String)) -> String {  
        return ""  
    }  

    func anotherProtocolMethod() -> Int {  
        return 1  
    }  
}
```

The error occurs on the line myValue is assigned, it reads:
error: value of type 'NSObject -> () ->MyClass has no member anotherProtocolMethod

Is there a way to make this work without moving myValue into the class extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the extension. This line would be illegal in any case:

```
var myValue = self.anotherProtocolMethod() // an instance property
```

A stored instance property cannot be directly initialized by calling an instance method, because at initialization time the instance is exactly what does not yet exist.

Comment: A good solution is to declare the property `lazy`. See the answer to the linked question.

Comment: Or use a computed property instead of a stored property. See my book for further discussion: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_properties

Comment: Thanks for the answer. A computed readonly property works great for my use case.

Comment: Good - it looked to me like that might work for what you were doing, but I couldn't be sure. Thanks for reporting back.